# Read custom format in datetimepicker c#

Tags: c#, winforms, format, custom-controls, datetimepicker

I want to do dateTimePicker to choose and read only year. This is my code, but when on third row where is  dateTimePicker1.Value it's someone else because when i open file is show me hour, date, month and  year. I trying to change value with customformat but make me mistake and want to change to string. Whan I change to string like: string dt = dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat; started it give me the same result like value. Where is the problem?

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom; //1
                dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy"; //2
    DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value; //3
                fp.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End); //4
                bw.Write(dt.ToString()); //5
```

Comment: `datetimepicker1.Value.Year` will give you the year part. `datetimepicker1.Value` returns a `DateTime` object regardless of the Custom Format. The Custom Format is purely for display in the `DateTimePicker`, it doesn't change what is returned.

Comment: It seems you need a `NumericUpDownControl`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just **ToString** method:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

dateTimePicker.ValueAsDate.ToShortDateString("D/M/Y")